# Exporting animated gifs; "AnimationRepetitions"->1 doesn't work

Tags: export, animation

I'm trying to export a table of graphics into a gif animated file with just one repetition.

```
Export["C:\Race.gif", t, "AnimationRepetitions" -> 1]
```

It doesn't work. The exported gif repeats and repeats over.

What should I do?

Comment: How do you know who is failing there? The Gif's generator or the renderer?

Comment: @belisarius You mean the program which opens my gif's may fail to repeat it once, don't you?

Comment: Yep. See (for example) http://superuser.com/a/159216/38729

Comment: @belisarius You're right! I changed the code to "AnimationRepetitions" -> 0 (instead of 1) and opened the gif in Chrome. It ran just once. Thanks.

Comment: @Öskå: Deleting the question is worse! Behzad should [post the solution as an answer instead](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Öskå Well, I searched the net before posting the question, and found out that the same problem had occured to other people. So I decided to ask for a solution. I posted an answer to my question.

Comment: @Behzad Good then :) I'm deleting my comments.

Answer (score 4):

**Solved.** I changed the code to `"AnimationRepetitions" -> 0` (instead of `1`) and opened the gif in Chrome. It ran just once.
My bad! I had not considered trying another way to open the gif. I overtrusted my gif renderer.

Comment: This option gives error in 11.3 `The value 0 specified for the option AnimationRepetitions is invalid`