# How to make animated gif file play once in 11.3?

Tags: bugs, export, animation, gif-format

There is similar question here [exporting-animated-gifs-animationrepetitions-1-doesnt-work](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64566/exporting-animated-gifs-animationrepetitions-1-doesnt-work)

But the accepted answer there no longer works in 11.3, which is to use `"AnimationRepetitions" -> 0` as it gives error

```
Export::erropts: The value 0 specified for the option AnimationRepetitions is invalid.
```

I need the animated gif file to play once and stop. By default, with no options, the animation in the Chrome browser always plays 2 times and then stops. I also tested it in FireFox.

The help page on [AnimationRepetitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnimationRepetitions.html) does not say anything about how to make it play only once. Using `"AnimationRepetitions" -> 1` has no effect also, it plays 2 times always then stops.  Has this changed in 11.3 from the time of the accepted answer above?

Here is MWE

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
r=Table[
   Grid[{{Row[{"time ",t}]},
   {
     Plot[Sin[t x],{x,-2 Pi,2 Pi}]
   }}],
   {t,0,10,0.5}
];
Export["anim0.gif",r,"AnimationRepetitions"->1]
```

loading the above animation to the browser (drag the file and drop it on a web page that is open), will show it plays 2 times.

question: How to make it play only once in 11.3? Is there other options to use?
Version 11.3 on windows 7 home edition.

Comment: I suspect a bug. It seems that the exported GIF animation always plays `"AnimationRepetitions"`$+1$ times in my MMA 11.3, and as you said, a value of $0$ for `"AnimationRepetitions"` is not accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in 11.3 and there is no way to export a gif that will only play once. That bug will be fixed in the next release.

Here is a simple workaround you can use:

```
ExportSingleAnimationGIF[fname_String, expr_, opts___] := 
With[{
    bytes = StringToByteArray[ExportString[ expr, "GIF", opts, CharacterEncoding -> "ISO8859-1"], "ISO8859-1"],
    loop = {33, 255, 11, 78, 69, 84, 83, 67, 65, 80, 69, 50, 46, 48, 3, 1, _, _, 0}
},
    With[{
        gifBytes = Join @@ SequenceSplit[Normal[bytes], loop]
    }, 
        BinaryWrite[fname, gifBytes];
        Close[fname];
        fname
    ]
]
```

You call it with the same arguments and options as you would pass to `Export` but obviously `"AnimationRepetitions"` will be ignored. It should always produce a GIF that only plays once.

Comment: What changes do I need to do to make the animation loop indefinitely? I have version 11.2. In my browser the animation runs exactly twice. Irrespective of the value I give to `"AnimationRepetitions"`. If you prefer, I can write another question about it.